# Are there any vaishanava schools that allow occasional meat consumption?

Tags: vaishnavism

It is believed that orthodox vaishnava path is more rigidly against meat consumption than other sampradayas.
I want to know if there is any exception to it. Are there any vaishnava schools that accept occasional non vegetarians ?

Comment: ' vaishnava path is more rigidly against meat consumption than other sampradayas' are there any non-Vaishnavite sects that encourage meat consumption?

Comment: Animal sacrifice preferablly a goat, is done in honour of Jwala Narsimha. Also, at Kallalagar temple this is followed. A few temples in Assam too follow the step where Pancharatra or Shakta Agams are used.

Comment: btw, that sacrificed goat goes to svarga is proper vedic yagna rules are followed. @Chamundadas

Comment: @mar Indeed, without a doubt. Even tantras and purans say the same.